# How to divide the slide of Wordpress theme in 2 parts using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, slide

I need to divide the Slide in two parts -

- Left side - sliding
- Right side - fixed image, preferentially I'll set manually

The code, I've tried to add `col-md-6` but not working...

```
<div id="home-flexslider" class="clearfix">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;">
        <div class="desc-wrap">
        </div>
        <img src="/theme/crud/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slide-three.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item;">
        <div class="desc-wrap">
          <div class="slide-description">
            <h3>
                                                Custom Slide Without Target URL                                        </h3>
            <p>Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="/theme/crud/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slide-two.jpg" alt="Custom Slide Without Target URL">
      </li>
      <li class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;">
        <div class="desc-wrap">
          <div class="slide-description">
            <h3>
                                                <a href="http://#">Custom Slide Sample</a>                                        </h3>
            <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p><a href="http://#custom-url" class="know-more">Know More</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="http://#custom-url">
              <img src="/theme/crud/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slide-one.jpg" alt="Custom Slide Sample">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="/theme/crud/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slide-one.jpg" alt="Custom Slide Sample">
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
      <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `width: 50%`? That works for me (using Inspect Element to add style). Then you can add `width: 50%` to your other div / image, then set them both to `display: inline-block`

Comment: I haven't, i'll try, thanks for help me!

Comment: Druzion, thanks a lot, this helped me!!!!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: Done! Marked answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `width: 50%` to the slider. This will set the `width` to `50%` of the width of the page (in your case anyway).

You can them add `width: 50%` to the image you want to add.

Then to both elements, add `display: inline-block`. This will ensure they display next to each other rather than under each other.